# OpenID use in enterprise environments?

Tags: authentication, openid, enterprise

Are there examples of large enterprises that use OpenID internally?  I've read articles that speculated it would be done but haven't found any specific examples.

Is there even readily available software for an enterprise to set up their own OpenID provider backed by their LDAP or ActiveDirectory infrastructure already in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Atlassian suite.  [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/crowd) provides an OpenID server that can connect to an LDAP server for it's backing store.

It mostly depends on the applications that the enterprise uses.  If it is a heterogeneous environment, it wouldn't be hard to change the authentication code.  Most enterprises use a mix of applications though, and they all need to be modified to support OpenID as login credentials.

Comment: Thanks.  We use Confluence actually but I didn't know about Crowd.

Comment: I have Crowd set up as my OpenID server, but don't use it much internally yet because all my apps are based on Spring Security (the "heterogeneous" reference earlier).  But if for instance I had Oracle Financials, one can pretty much assume that it doesn't support OpenID yet, so it wouldn't buy me anything.